# player dontdestroyonload object when dying causes infinite reloading bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So for context this code is for a metroidvania style game with lots of different rooms that are different scenes this game also includes lots of upgrades that are permanently unlocked by the player that the player needs to keep while dead the player is coded to not unload between scenes.

However when running the code as soon as the player is killed the game rapidly loads and unloads the scene making the game unplayable:

[image: image showing the game in the unity game engine playing the game the player is now dead and the game is continually loading and unloading the player and scene]

code for health and respawning in my player is here:

```
   public int maxHealth = 5;
public float timeInvincible = 2.0f;

public int health { get { return currentHealth; } }
int currentHealth;

bool isInvincible;
float invincibleTimer;

public int respawn;
public bool canDie = true;
private bool isDead = false;
UIManager uiManager;


public static BasicPlayerMovement Instance;

private void Awake()
{
    //prevents 2 instances of the player existing at any given time
    if(Instance != null && Instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    currentHealth = maxHealth;
}

void Update()
{

if (isInvincible)
    {
        invincibleTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (invincibleTimer < 0)
            isInvincible = false;
    }

    if ((currentHealth <= 0) && (canDie == true))
    {
        StartCoroutine(PlayerDeath());
        

    }
}


 public void ChangeHealth(int amount)
{
    if (amount < 0)
    {
        if (isInvincible)
            return;

        isInvincible = true;
        invincibleTimer = timeInvincible;
    }
    currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth + amount, 0, maxHealth);
    Debug.Log(currentHealth + "/" + maxHealth);


}

 private IEnumerator PlayerDeath()
{
   
    isDead = true;
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(respawn);

   
    yield return null; //new WaitForSeconds(0.9f);


}

public void Respawned()
{
    isDead = false;
    currentHealth = maxHealth;
}
```

Here is the code for the respawn point:

```
public class RespawnPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool interacted;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.CompareTag("Player") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        interacted = true;
    }
}
}
```

code for my game manager:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public string transitionedFromScene;
public Vector2 respawnPoint;
public Vector2 platformingRespawnPoint;
[SerializeField] RespawnPoint rP;

    public static GameManager instance { get; private set; }
//this code carrys the game manager object between scenes saving the scene the player moved from
private void Awake()
{
    if(instance != null && instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    rP = FindObjectOfType<RespawnPoint>();
}

public void RespawnPlayer()
{
    if(rP != null)
    {
        if (rP.interacted)
        {
            respawnPoint = rP.transform.position;
        }
        
    }
    else
    {
        respawnPoint = platformingRespawnPoint;
    }

    BasicPlayerMovement.Instance.transform.position = respawnPoint;
    BasicPlayerMovement.Instance.Respawned();
}
}
```

Comment: How many times is `StartCoroutine(PlayerDeath());` executed? Use the debugger or add some logging to find out. Why is it a coroutine anyway?

Comment: i doubt it will fix it but i would put the dont destroy and finds etc inside the instance = section eg the you're keeping this one part of the if.. because destroy is not immediate mayube its half doing the next bit of code? you said it loads and unloads.. your respawnpoints will need refinding each time the scene loads.. because they are remade.